# How to display epub file content in iPhone application without using UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, epub

First I created an application loading epub file content into UIWebView. But the content displayed in simulator but not displayed in iPhone device.I don't know how to get the content in devices also. Is any settings need to set in devices? Can u please help me.  or Is any possible to load epub file in iPhone application without using UIWebView?

Thanks in Advance......

Comment: this link may help u http://www.thoughtshots.com/2011/04/open-epub-files-on-your-ios-device-without-syncing/

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but i added epub file directly into UIWebView. Can u please if have any source code provide me...

Comment: you mentioned ur question "without using uiwebview". :):)

Comment: Yes, Actually first i did by using UIWebView, I got content in Simulator but the content not displayed in devices. that is my problem...

Comment: if you provide some code, it would be easier to try and help...

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something works in the Simulator and not the device, check the file name VERY carefully. If the capitalization in your code is not the same as the file it will work in the simulator, but not the device.

Comment: In that loading epub file into UIWebView. It loads some pages and some pages not displayed.This is the problem i faced it now.